# Who did Nachmanides marry?

Tags: middle-ages, jews

I would like to know who [Nachmanides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachmanides) married. What was her name and how old was he when he married her? I asked everyone I knew and googled it a thousand times but I could not find an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. It would be helpful if you tell us exactly where you have already searched and what you did find. Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: Maybes wives? This page talks about a legend surrounding his wife, and also says that he had one who became Catholic. http://www.5tjt.com/debunking-a-ramban-myth-by-rabbi-yair-hoffman/

Comment: first of all in that article it says that she is not christian- "no histories indicate one iota that there was Â a descendant of the Ramban or his wife who became Catholic." second of all i just read the book that they are advertising- its amazing!

Comment: by *its amazing!* , do you mean that book provided an answer to your question ?

Comment: That quote is confusing. I took it to possibly mean that he had a Catholic wife, but that there is no proof of their children. Maybe it means there's no proof of his Catholic wife.

Comment: sorry i mean its just a good book it made me think about the question... sorry.

Comment: Please edit into the question; comments get deleted and questions should stand alone. The question should contain all the information you have to assist with research.